# How to change username and password for localhost database in azure data studio on linux?

Tags: javascript, sql, linux, t-sql, azure-data-studio

I use azure data studio for my localhost database on manjaro linux. I want to change my username and password for the localhost database, but I don't know how. I know I can't do that with a query and I searched on the internet how to do that but all I found was instructions on how to create a database. How to change username and password for localhost database in azure data studio on linux? Do I need to install something more in order to work?

Also I need to use this database for the back end of a project that I write in javascript.

Comment: Use `ALTER LOGIN`.